# Multiple network interfaces with netplan

Tags: networking, routing, netplan

So in short, I have 3 network interface on my Ubuntu Server 18.04

ens160 - LAN 192.168.1.50/24 set by dhcp

ens192 - LAB 10.10.10.50/24  set by dhcp

ens224 - SAN 10.10.15.50/24  static ip.

They are on the same router as different VLAN's.

I can't seem to ping the server on both interfaces if they are up at the same time. 
If one is down I can ping the other but if they are both up only one is accessible.

My netplan config is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
# Lab Network
    ens160:
     dhcp4: yes
     dhcp6: no
# VM Network    
    ens192:
     dhcp4: yes
     dhcp6: no
# Internal Storage Network  #This is not routable anyways
    ens224:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses: [10.10.15.50/24]
```

I'm guessing there is some routing issue here but not sure how to fix it.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens160
default         therouter.test  0.0.0.0         UG    200    0        0 ens192
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens160
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens160
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens192
therouter.test  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    200    0        0 ens192
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have two default routes on the two interfaces, both provided by DHCP.  If you try to ping the 192.168.1.50 address from another machine not on the 192.168.1.0/24 network, the response will be sent via the 10.10.10.50 interface, which is not what the network is expecting.

To have two remotely-accessible addresses, you likely need to configure policy-based routing instead of accepting default routes from dhcp.